# How to prove $f$ is Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Define $$f(t):=\int_{-t}^{t} g(t, y)dy$$ where $g(t,y)$ is Lipschitz and $g(t,y)=\phi(x(t,y))=x^2/(1+x^2)$ is smooth function. How to prove $f$ is Lipschitz?

I try to use the mean value theorem for integral, 
$$\left|f(t_1)-f(t_2)\right|\leq\left|\int_{-t_1}^{t_1} g(t,y)dy-\int_{-t_2}^{t_2}g(t,y)dy\right|\leq\left|2t_1g(\xi,y)-2t_2g(\phi,y)\right|$$ where $\xi\in(-t_1,t_1)$ and $\phi\in(-t_2,t_2)$.

Why the last term is bounded by $K|t_1-t_2|$ for a constant $K$?

Comment: As written, $f$ is not necessarily (globally) Lipschitz. Consider $g(t,y) = e^y$. May be you want some integratibility condition for $g$ or only locally Lipschitz ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true.  Take $g(t,x)=x^{2}$. This is smooth but $f(t)=2t^{3}/3$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks. How about $g(t,y)=\phi(x(t,y))=x^2/(1+x^2)$?

Comment: Add the condition about $g$ is Lip?